# Scrapy: select last decendant node?

Tags: python, scrapy, selector

I have a `dict` with selectors which I use to get data:

```
for key, selector in selectors.items():
    data[key] = response.css(selector).get().strip()
```

One of the selectors is `span::text`, but sometimes the text is wrapped in an additional `a` tag. My solution is to make that entry a list including `span a::text`:

```
for key, selector in selectors.items():
    if type(selector) == list:
        for sel in selector:
            data[key] = response.css(sel).get().strip()
            if data[key] not in ["", None]: break
    else:
        data[key] = response.css(selector).get().strip()
```

Is there a way to change the selector so that it will get the text I want whether there's an `a` tag or not? I would like the script to be a single line with `.get().strip()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can just use `'span *::text'`.

to Demonstrate:

```
In [1]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [2]: html1 = '<span><a>text contents</a></span>'

In [3]: html2 = '<span>text contents</span>'

In [4]: selector1 = Selector(text=html1)

In [5]: selector2 = Selector(text=html2)

In [6]: selector1.css('span *::text').get().strip()
Out[6]: 'text contents'

In [7]: selector2.css('span *::text').get().strip()
Out[7]: 'text contents'
```

Comment: Should've thought of that, thanks!